# WebDriverIO Selenium pass command line arguments into Chrome from config.js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver-io, chrome-web-driver

I need chrome to run with disable-web-security flag for my UI tests. How can I inject any commands using wdio.config file (http://webdriver.io/).

```
  capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set any chrome flags within the desired capabilities using `goog:chromeOptions`

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        args: ['disable-web-security']
    }
}]
```

Check out [the chromedriver docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) for more information on the chromeOptions object.

Answer (score 7):

This ended up being the correct syntax, thanks Christian!

```
  capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
         'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--disable-web-security']
        }
    }]
```

Answer (score 5):

Something has been changed because in `@wdio/cli` version `5.11.13` and `chromedriver` version `76.0.0` I cannot pass parameter `chromeOptions` - result: `invalid argument: unrecognized capability: chromeOptions`.

I did some research and passing `goog:chromeOptions` works:

```
  capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: ['--disable-web-security'],
    },
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable javascript in the browser using webdriverio, in your wdio.config you'll need

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
     'goog:chromeOptions': {
            "args" : ["start-fullscreen"],
            "prefs" : {
                    'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2
            }
    }
}]
```