# How to execute selenium-webdriver / protractor commands interactively in chrome devtools command line?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, google-chrome-devtools

How to:

- write unfinished test
- set breakpoint at the end of unfinished test
- enter repl / command line / chrome devtools
- execute selenium commands in repl / command line / chrome devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to setup development environment where I can execute selenium actions in chrome devtools (interactively)

1.write example test with debugger breakpoint in the middle

```
const faker = require('faker')

describe('login', function() {
  this.timeout(30 * 1000)

  describe("when user doesn't exist", () => {
    it.only('should not login', async () => {
      await browser.get(`/login`)

      // debugger breakpoints

      // I'm using `await $('div').getText();` command to force selenium evaluate promise.

      // More about how promises are evaluated in chrome devtools here
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852917/how-to-run-asynchronous-code-in-chrome-devtools-when-script-execution-is-paused

      // use F8 in chrome devtools to execute `await $('div').getText();` and stop on next `debugger` breakpoint
      // use ctrl-[ and ctrl-] to switch between panels in chrome devtools

      debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();debugger; await $('div').getText();

      await $('#gb-email').sendKeys('foo@mail.com')
    })
  })
})
```

2. run protractor in inspect mode

`"test:debug": "node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 ./node_modules/.bin/protractor ./config.js",`

3. go to chrome://inspect/#devices and click inspect link to launch chrome devtools

[image: 2018-12-27-20 30 29-screenshot]

4. press f8 to continue test and stop on first breakpoint

[image: 2018-12-27-20 31 37-screenshot]

5. now you can execute selenium commands interactively in console

[image: 2018-12-27-20 31 52-screenshot]
[image: 2018-12-27-20 31 54-screenshot]

6. press f8 to continue execution ([promises can't be evaluated when thread is paused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852917/how-to-run-asynchronous-code-in-chrome-devtools-when-script-execution-is-paused)), `await $('div').getText();` will force selenium to execute statement (selenium promises are weird type of promises, for example even `await(new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(() => { resolve('dummy'); }, 0); }))` doesnt force selenium to execute statement`)
7. PROFIT

[image: 2018-12-27-20 32 11-screenshot]

---

BONUS

config.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: "mocha",
  baseUrl: process.env.APP_URL,
  seleniumAddress: process.env.HUB_URL,
  specs: ["src/specs/**/*.js"],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740900/webdriverio-selenium-pass-command-line-arguments-into-chrome-from-config-js-file
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        // disable chrome's wakiness
        'disable-infobars',
        'disable-extensions',

        // allow http
        'disable-web-security',

        // other
        'lang=en',
        'no-default-browser-check',
        'no-sandbox',

        // not working
        // 'start-maximized',
      ],
      prefs: {
        // disable chrome's annoying password manager
        'profile.password_manager_enabled': false,
        'credentials_enable_service': false,
        'password_manager_enabled': false,

        download: {
          default_directory:   process.env.REMOTE_DOWNLOAD_DIR,
          prompt_for_download: false,
          directory_upgrade:   true,
          extensions_to_open:  '',
        },
        plugins: {
          plugins_disabled: ['Chrome PDF Viewer'], // disable viewing pdf files after download
        },
      },
    },
  },
  onPrepare: function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true

    // because --start-maximized arg is not working
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()

    // patch require function to run babel before loading files
    require("@babel/register")

    // fix regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    // require("@babel/polyfill")
  },
  mochaOpts: {
    enableTimeouts: false,
    file: ['./src/hooks/index.js'],
  },
  allScriptsTimout: 15000,
}
```

N.B. duplicated here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5099#issuecomment-450209485